# Parse response from API

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jsp

Sorry if this looks like simple but please help me finding a solution.

When I call an [API](https://www.followmee.com/api/tracks.aspx?key=f8b18868ed1530d08880da811a86a2db&username=TirecoInc&output=json&function=currentfordevice&deviceid=10941818) it returns response and I need to find "Latitude" and "Longitude" values from it. I am not able to make it work. I use JQuery/JavaScript.

Response form API:

```
{"Data":[{"DeviceName":"HAY-JOVAN-5103657285","DeviceID":"10941818","Date":"2015-08-12T17:02:42-07:00","Latitude":37.65438,"Longitude":-122.13830,"Type":"GPS","Speed(mph)":0,"Speed(km/h)":0,"Altitude(ft)":-82,"Altitude(m)":-25,"Accuracy":11}]}
```

When tried something like this but not what I want:

```
$.each(jsonResult, function () {
                    $.each(this, function (k, v) {
                        console.log("k:" + k, " v:" + v);
                    });
                });
```

Can you please help me finding "Latitude" and "Longitude" values from it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try with:

```
console.log('Latitude', v.Latitude);
console.log('Longitude', v.Longitude);
```

Comment: Thank you! It's working. Really appreciate the help.

Comment: @user704988 If you find my answer helpful, remember to accept it.